# When is the locals dictionary set?

Tags: python, namespaces, symbol-table

A module holds a dictionary to keep track of itscontext, such as the names defined at some point of the execution. This dictionary can be accessed through [`vars(module)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) (or `module.__dict__`) if `module` was imported, or by a call to the [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) built-in function in the module itself:

> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table.

But I found myself a bit confused, when I tried accessing the locals dictionary from a function. The output of a script containing only the following is an empty dictionary:

```
def list_locals():
    print(locals())

list_locals()
```

But on the other hand, if a script contains exclusively the following, the output is the expected dictionary, containing `__name__`, `__doc__` and the other module-level variables:

```
print(locals())
```

So, when is the content of the locals dictionary set?
In addition, what does "update" mean in the definition of the `locals` function?

Comment: At the module level try `print(locals() is globals())`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yep, that was part of my confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The namespace of a module is the *global* namespace, accessed through [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals). There is no separate locals namespace, so `locals()`, outside of functions, just returns the global namespace.

Only functions have a local namespace. Note that `locals()` is a one-way reflection of that namespace; the CPython implementation for functions is highly optimised and you can't add or alter local variables through the `locals()` dictionary. The dictionary returned by `locals()` is updated whenever the namespace has changed between calls to that function.

Note also that things like list / dict / set comprehensions, generator expressions and class bodies are in reality executed as functions too, albeit with different namespace rules. In such contexts `locals()` will also return the separate function local namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `locals()` more than once during the same function call, it will return the same dictionary.

```
>>> def f():
...     d = locals()
...     assert 'd' not in d
...     locals()
...     assert 'd' in d
...     assert d is locals()
...     print(d)
... 
>>> f()
{'d': {...}}
```

"Update" in this case means that the contents of this dictionary are updated to reflect the current scope of local variables that exist, but if you kept a reference to this dictionary then that dictionary will still be used.

Notice also that the locals dictionary doesn't contain a key for `'f'`, even though you could have accessed it during the course of the function. In case it's not obvious, that's a global, not a local.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation about the meaning of "update". Although I obviously mixed up `locals` and `globals`, I'd say that the documentation is somewhat evasive about that behaviour. Thanks again for the clarification.